# Codeigniter REST Client GET/POST format

Tags: php, rest, codeigniter

I am trying to access my rest api via a url. This is my request

```
$this->load->library('rest', array(
            'server' => 'testurl',
            'http_user' => $this->api_configuration()['username'],
            'http_pass' => $this->api_configuration()['password'],
            'http_auth' => 'basic' 
        ));
$this->rest->get();
```

I get this error when I use this  Missing argument 1 for REST::get()
May I know what are the arguments required? I haven't found anywhere that explains.

Answer (score 0):

The method get of rest library require a first argument called `$uri` see:

https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restclient

and

https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restclient/blob/master/libraries/Rest.php#L117

The use should be:

```
$this->rest->get('edit/post/1');
```

where the first argument is the path in defined rest server

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, so if my url is www.url.com/Countries_WS/GetAll ? I have tried using $this->rest->get("Countries_WS/GetAll") but that leads to a 404. Also, there are no inputs for this call.

Comment: are you initializing the library, see this example, https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restclient#usage

Comment: Well I'm loading the rest library. I don't have the spark line though. I can't use spark on my server

Comment: ensure the `server` config end with `/`, e.g.  'server' => 'http://restserver.com/customapi/api/',

Comment: Yeah tried that as well. I ended up using curl. Thanks though